# breaking down use cases of different storage methods in iOS apps

Tags: ios, core-data, nsuserdefaults, keychain

I'm learning to build iOS swift apps, and I'd appreciate guidance on what storage options to use for different parts of my app. Perhaps examples of how other professional apps architect their storage would be helpful too.

To be specific, I see my options as

1. an independent MySQL DB
2. amazon s3
3. core data
4. nsuserdefaults
5. keychain

The app allows users to see/stream/download/upload videos and photos to their account/app as well as do all the normal voting, customizing user preferences, etc. This is an arbitrary app example though. A social media app storage would also be a good case study for me.

Given the variety of functionality to implement, I'm curious as to the best practices for storage architecture in maintaining sessions, persistence, and security.

Right now all I've implemented is having the user create an account and login by doing http requests to the MySQL DB. And i upload and download media from my s3. Each time user data is pulled anew from the DB.

Should i cache/archive stuff into coredata to make it faster for the user?

If a user wants the app to "remember me", where is that data stored?

Instead of straight http calls for logging in, should i do something with keychain? (keychains are the only thing i haven't implemented yet in that list. The rest I've messed with independently)

I've also heard nsuserdefaults is only to be used for user preferences.

Thanks for all advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes You should use core data for better performance.
Core Data would be a much better tool for the job:

->No mismatch between cache index file and actual data stored;

->Trivial querying;

->Nice and easy object oriented code.

**NSUserDefaults**

If you want to add Remember me option you have to use NSUserDefaults. It will store in plist file. For more information you should go through [this](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/ios-application-security-part-20-local-data-storage-nsuserdefaults-coredata-sqlite-plist-files/).

**KeyChain**

Sensitive data like passwords and keys should be stored in the Keychain. Apple's Keychain Services Programming Guide states that a "keychain is an encrypted container that holds passwords for multiple applications and secure services. Keychains are secure storage containers, which means that when the keychain is locked, no one can access its protected contents". Moreover, in iOS, each application only has access to its own keychain items.
You interact with the Keychain by passing in a dictionary of key-value pairs that you want to find or create. Each key represents a search option or an attribute of the item in the keychain.

Comment: You do not "have to use" `NSUserDefaults` and it is almost always the wrong choice for iOS.

Comment: For small amount of data we can use defaults @Zaph

Comment: You can but that is rarely a good idea. Note that amount other things it is based on string based keys so there is no type checking. It is easily accessed from a connected computer. There is an extra step to know if the item exists, this is a particular problem with BOOLs. It is subject to the "Broken Window" syndrome. Instead just use a data model and save it to and restore from a file using `NSArchiver`. This works well as more items are added to the data model.

Comment: Thanks for the break down. Does it change things if I also want to maintain a webapp in parallel to my app? The webapp would use mysql. How would I balance the mysql with the core data/key chain and keep everything in sync.

Comment: do you guys think using an update script to keep changes in sync is better or do you think sticking to one source for data storage would be better? what do other apps do?